# Mouse clicks on next song

Tags: keyboard, mouse

For a few days I have had an issue where my mouse keeps clicking without me doing so. After a lot of trial and error I believe have found the source of my problem: the "next song" media key on my keyboard.

If I use the computer normally, no mouse clicks occur. However, as soon as I press "next song" clicks start happening at random intervals. If I unplug the keyboard, the clicking continues for a short period (as if there was a click buffer). I have to wait about 20 seconds before I can plug the keyboard back in. Then everything works fine again. I've repeated this test for a few hours now and it definitely seems like a problem with the key.

Unfortunately after a lot of searching online I can't seem to find a reason as to why this might be happening. I have uninstalled all of the drivers related to the keyboard and the issue still occurs. I'm at a loss.

My keyboard is a Microsoft Sidewinder X4.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried one more thing and it solved the problem. It turns out that you can infact map macros to the media keys on the keyboard. Both the play/pause button and the "next song" button were mapped to a macro that clicks the mouse at random intervals.

Uninstalling the drivers didn't work because the keyboard has its on memory. I thought I had better post my solution incase anyone else has the same problem. Attached is an image of the macro that was assigned to it. I still don't have any idea how the macro got assigned in the first place.

[image]

Comment: By default this won't happen. Either you accidentally pressed the record button and that media key so it recorded you clicking and then playing it back, or someone else is playing a prank on you.